# Constrain Vector of DataType to be of particular abstract type

Tags: julia

Is it possible to create a function which takes a `::Vector{DataType}` but constrains all members to be types which inherit from a particular abstract type?

Example:

```
# this code works but does not constrain the type
function foo{D<:DataType}(arr::Vector{D})
    ...
end

# this is kind of the syntax I'd like, but Type{Int} !<: Type{Integer}
function bar{D<:Type{Integer}}(arr::Vector{D})
    ...
end
```

Thank you

Comment: `Type` is an parametric type, so its type parameter is invariant. why not use `function bar{T<:Integer}(arr::Vector{Type{T}})`?

Comment: @GnimucKey: Thank you for the suggestion. I am having trouble creating an array matching that form: ```bar{T<:Integer}(arr::Vector{Type{T}}) = println(arr)```
bar (generic function with 1 method)

```bar([Int64, Int32])```
ERROR: `bar` has no method matching bar(::Array{DataType,1}).  Is there a clever way to use `convert`?

Comment: hmm, i find i just jump from one pit into another. that definition won't work! i'll post an answer for explanation, since there is not enough comment room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just to clarify why `function bar{T<:Integer}(arr::Vector{Type{T}}) = println(arr)` won't work.

**in a nutshell, this is because [julia's type parameter is invariant](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/types/#man-parametric-types)**.

firstly, take a look a OP's definition:

```
function bar{D<:Type{Integer}}(arr::Vector{D})
    ...
end
```

the problem here, as OP pointed out, is `Type{Int} !<: Type{Integer}`.
the reason is that `Type{T}` is a parametric type, even though `Int <: Integer`, we don't have `Type{Int} <: Type{Integer}`.

"bearing in mind"(yes, that's sarcasm) that the type parameter of julia's parametric type is invariant, i suggested to use this version:

```
function bar{T<:Integer}(arr::Vector{Type{T}})
    ...
end
```

it seems good! this time i'm using `T` instead of `Type{T}`, so i won't fall into the pit of `Type{Int} !<: Type{Integer}`.

however, as i wrote down that comment, i had just fallen into another pit -- **`Vector{}` is also a parametric type**. even if `DataType <: Type{T}`, we don't have `Vector{DataType} <: Vector{Type{T}}`.

<strike>as a result</strike>, a error will occur when running `bar([Int64, Int32])`.

```
julia> bar([Int64, Int32])
ERROR: MethodError: `bar` has no method matching bar(::Array{DataType,1})

julia> methods(bar)
bar{T<:Integer}(arr::Array{Type{T<:Integer},1})

julia> [Int64, Int32]
2-element Array{DataType,1}:
 Int64
 Int32
```

### EDIT:

hmm, it seems that this problem is not that simple. the key point here is the mysterious relationship between `DataType` and `Type{T}`.

```
# we know that DataType is a subtype of Type{T},
# where T is a `TypeVar` \in [Bottom, Any].
julia> subtypes(Type)
3-element Array{Any,1}:
 DataType       
 TypeConstructor
 Union   

julia> S = TypeVar(:S, Union{}, Integer, true)
S<:Integer

# but Type{S} is not a subtype of DataType
julia> Type{S} <: DataType
false

julia> Type{S} <: Type
true
```

i therefore conclude that it's impossible to make `::Vector{DataType}` work in your case.

1. `DataType` has NO type parameters.
2. the below definition won't work, which seems like a bug.

   ```
   julia> a = Array(Type{S}, 2)
   2-element Array{Type{S<:Integer},1}:
    #undef
    #undef

   julia> a[1] = Type{Int32}      # or Int32
   Type{Int32}

   julia> a[2] = Type{Float32}    # or Float32
   Type{Float32}

   julia> a
   2-element Array{Type{S<:Integer},1}:
    Type{Int32} 
    Type{Float32}
   ```

i'll post a question about this strange behavior. @Mageek

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is possible (cleanly) with a compile-time check.  You could consider using a `Val` type, but this will be messy and probably slower.  I would just make it a run-time check:

```
julia> function bar{T}(::Type{T}, arr::Vector{DataType})
           if all(x->x<:T, arr)
               println("ok")
           else
               println("bad")
           end
       end
bar (generic function with 1 method)

julia> bar(Integer, [Int,Int32])
ok

julia> bar(Integer, [Int,Int32,Float64])
bad
```

What's your use case for this?  There might be an alternative that's cleaner.

Comment: Thanks! My use-case is fitting a bunch of models to a dataset. Consider Distributions.jl, where fit_mle() takes a DataType. I'd like to loop through my Distribution types and fit a model for each.

Comment: I'll accept the post since no solution is possible. If someone does find one please let us know!

Comment: Did you see Gnumic Key's answer (posted in a comment) above?

Comment: @tholy that method will not work, please take a look at my explanation below.